# why is iOS launch screen very slow?

Tags: ios

My iOS app launch screen takes about 3 - 5 seconds. I have a map that will load after the launch screen. My users have to wait for the launch screen to load and then wait another 3 seconds for the map to load.
Is there a way to minimize launch screen time?

Comment: Without code there is no way to tell. Check your loading sequences. If you are trying to do all sorts of things while the app is launching or right after the app is launching, then you are sure to slow it down. So many other things come to mind, but matt covered pretty much the basics below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this delay means that *you* are doing something very wrong during launch. Your job is to launch *immediately*. Indeed, the WatchDog app will kill you dead if you don't.

There are excellent WWDC videos on this topic, and you should watch them. But in general there are two ways to go wrong:

- You must do *nothing* time-consuming on the main thread. If you have a time-consuming thing to do, like loading your map or networking, you must do that on a background thread. You need to *get out of the way* so that the runtime can launch your app *now*.
- Just the other way around, you must *not* touch the interface on any other thread but the main thread. Doing this wrong causes just the kind of delay you are reporting. Do your *work* on a background thread, but then get back on the *main* thread to talk to your views, view controllers, etc.

Finally, I should point out that you *might* be able to get *some* idea what you're doing wrong by using Instruments. Unfortunately it works rather badly against app launch, but it can be worth a try. Above all, watch those videos!