# My app crashes when not launched from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

Until today was running fine, with and without Xcode. But then I upgraded the device to iOS 14.2 beta and Xcode 12.1 to test some stuff. Then I ran the app with Xcode without problems but when I tried to run it without Xcode attached it simply crashes.

I'm guessing any of my 3rd party libraries might not be compatible with the coming iOS 14.2? But then how do I find which one?

How can I debug this if just happens when the app is not debugging?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I was able to use Xcode to retrieve this crash log:

```
 Incident Identifier: 457D137B-4C71-4234-B00C-A7FCFB54B83E
 CrashReporter Key:   8209fa6a3cb483ad2e2f83c4080e8b5156eec66d Hardware
 Model:      iPhone11,8 Process:             city [744] Path:          
 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB8D479E-0C9F-4A22-ABB0-6E4371CA3CA3/city.app/city
 Identifier:          com.myapp.app Version:             836 (0.97)
 Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Role:                Foreground
 Parent Process:      launchd [1] Coalition:           com.myapp.app
 [572]
 
 
 Date/Time:           2020-11-04 17:38:27.4634 +0100 Launch Time:      
 2020-11-04 17:38:07.3599 +0100 OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.2
 (18B91) Release Type:        User Baseband Version:    3.01.01 Report
 Version:      104
 
 Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Codes:
 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
 EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code
 0x8badf00d Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext|
 domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog
 transgression:  application<com.myapp.app>:744 exhausted real (wall
 clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground
 | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch |
 WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed
 total CPU time (seconds): 9.720 (user 9.720, system 0.000), 8% CPU", |
 "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.105, 0% CPU" | )
 reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive> Triggered by
 Thread:  0
 
 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00000001d217bf5c
 __ulock_wait + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001a4e71794 _dlock_wait + 56 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4e716c0 _dispatch_once_wait + 124 3   UIKitCore                      0x00000001a782c430 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader
 _loadInitializationContext] + 152 4   UIKitCore                        0x00000001a782c77c -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader
 applicationInitializationContext] + 32 5   UIKitCore                  
    0x00000001a7813394 -[_UIScreenInitialDisplayConfigurationLoader
 initialDisplayContext] + 180 6   UIKitCore                    
    0x00000001a7813680 +[UIScreen initialize] + 128 7   libobjc.A.dylib  
    0x00000001b97cdc58 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 24 8  
 libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001b97d4318
 initializeNonMetaClass + 716 9   libobjc.A.dylib              
    0x00000001b97d5910 initializeAndMaybeRelock+ 39184 (objc_class*,
 objc_object*, mutex_tt<false>&, bool) + 280 10  libobjc.A.dylib       
    0x00000001b97e4498 lookUpImpOrForward + 956 11  libobjc.A.dylib      
    0x00000001b97ce524 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68 12  UIKitCore         
    0x00000001a782cc80 _UIGetCurrentFallbackTraitCollection + 100 13 
 UIKitCore                      0x00000001a78299d8 +[UITraitCollection
 _currentTraitCollectionWithFallback:markFallback:] + 176 14  UIKitCore                         0x00000001a7831454 _UICurrentImageTraitCollection + 28 15  UIKitCore 
    0x00000001a78310f4 +[UIImageConfiguration
 _completeConfiguration:fromConfiguration:] + 164 16  UIKitCore                         0x00000001a77dfad0 +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:withConfiguration:]
 + 180 17  UnityFramework                   0x00000001059fbb38 +[LUTheme initialize] + 10468152 (LUTheme.m:150) 18  libobjc.A.dylib            
    0x00000001b97cdc58 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 24 19 
 libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001b97d4318
 initializeNonMetaClass + 716 20  libobjc.A.dylib              
    0x00000001b97d5910 initializeAndMaybeRelock+ 39184 (objc_class*,
 objc_object*, mutex_tt<false>&, bool) + 280 21  libobjc.A.dylib       
    0x00000001b97e4498 lookUpImpOrForward + 956 22  libobjc.A.dylib      
    0x00000001b97ce524 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68 23  UnityFramework    
    0x00000001059ddd00 +[LUConsoleLogEntry load] + 10345728
 (LUConsoleLogEntry.m:44) 24  libobjc.A.dylib              
    0x00000001b97dd21c load_images + 928 25  libdyld.dylib               
    0x00000001a4ec1840 invocation function for block in
 dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp+ 71744 (dyld3::closure::Image
 const*) + 224 26  libdyld.dylib                    0x00000001a4eb318c
 dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void + 12684 (unsigned
 int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 104 27  libdyld.dylib              
    0x00000001a4ec2344 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage+ 74564 (Diagnostics&,
 char const*, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool,
 bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 828 28  libdyld.dylib                
    0x00000001a4ec1e2c dyld3::AllImages::dlopen+ 73260 (Diagnostics&,
 char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*, bool) + 904 29
 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001a4ec3d14
 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 81172 (char const*, int, void*) + 372 30 
 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001a4eb5d44 dlopen_internal+
 23876 (char const*, int, void*) + 112 31  CoreFoundation              
    0x00000001a51d2124 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 140 32 
 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a51a1e10
 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 384 33  Foundation                     0x00000001a64d1908 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 336 34  city    
    0x0000000102533cb0 UnityFrameworkLoad() + 31920 (main.mm:12) 35  city
    0x0000000102533db4 main + 32180 (main.mm:25) 36  libdyld.dylib       
    0x00000001a4eb16c0 start + 4
 
 Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue:
 com.apple.uikit.applicationSupportClient Thread 1: 0  
 libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001d217b204 __psynch_mutexwait +
 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00000001ee698214
 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 92 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ee698164 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 216 3  
 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001a4ec3bec
 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 80876 (char const*, int, void*) + 76 4  
 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001a4eb5d44 dlopen_internal+
 23876 (char const*, int, void*) + 112 5   SoftLinking                 
    0x00000001e634bf50 _sl_dlopen_audited + 52 6   BoardServices         
    0x00000001be0cb160 __getRBSServiceInitializeSymbolLoc_block_invoke +
 84 7   BoardServices                   0x00000001be0c8720
 __34+[BSServiceManager sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 900 8   libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001a4e70db0
 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 9   libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001a4e725c8 _dispatch_once_callout + 32 10  BoardServices     
    0x00000001be0c8398 +[BSServiceManager sharedInstance] + 84 11 
 BoardServices                  0x00000001be0c0924
 +[BSServiceConnection _connectionWithEndpoint:clientContextBuilder:] + 324 12  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a9276a50
 __44-[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget]_block_invoke + 208 13  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001a4e70db0
 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 14  libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001a4e7f428 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete +
 60 15  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a9276938
 -[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget] + 184 16  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a9276160 -[UISApplicationSupportClient
 applicationInitializationContextWithParameters:] + 196 17  UIKitCore  
    0x00000001a782c5b0 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader
 _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke_2 + 228 18  UIKitCore                         0x00000001a782c4c0
 __UIAPPLICATION_IS_LOADING_INITIALIZATION_INFO_FROM_THE_SYSTEM__ + 28 19  UIKitCore                        0x00000001a782c498
 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 100 20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4e70db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 21 
 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001a4e725c8
 _dispatch_once_callout + 32 22  UIKitCore                      0x00000001a782c430 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader
 _loadInitializationContext] + 152 23  UIKitCore                        0x00000001a782c740 __70-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader
 startPreloadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 28 24 
 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001a4e6f24c
 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 25  libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001a4e70db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 26 
 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001a4e81a68
 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 656 27  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001a4e82120 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116 28 
 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001ee6947c8 _pthread_wqthread +
 216 29  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001ee69b75c
 start_wqthread + 8
 
 Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
     x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000001801   x3: 0x0000000000000000
     x4: 0x00000001a4e861c8   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000023
     x8: 0x0000000000001c07   x9: 0x0000000000001800  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000000000000000f    x12: 0x0000000000cb4333
 x13: 0x0300000204a4a729  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15:
 0x0000000204a4a728    x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x00000001a782c434
 x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000    x20:
 0x0000000204a5bf20  x21: 0x0000000001000002  x22: 0x0000000000001801 
 x23: 0x0000000000000008    x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25:
 0x00000002049efa7c  x26: 0x00000001029c39a0  x27: 0x00000002049ef000  
 x28: 0x00000001fad4b000   fp: 0x000000016d8cd840   lr:
 0x00000001a4e71794
     sp: 0x000000016d8cd820   pc: 0x00000001d217bf5c cpsr: 0x00000000    esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
 
 Binary Images: 0x10252c000 - 0x102533fff city arm64 
 <982dcb0901db3c84a30ab03723b50e64>
 /var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB8D479E-0C9F-4A22-ABB0-6E4371CA3CA3/city.app/city
 0x102918000 - 0x102987fff dyld arm64e 
 <a5f65ef3bd32370b9821b3e9cda294d2> /usr/lib/dyld 0x105000000 -
 0x109c5ffff UnityFramework arm64  <e59b3708514d3bbab0f36aa67ddd48c2>
 /var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB8D479E-0C9F-4A22-ABB0-6E4371CA3CA3/city.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
 0x1a4e6d000 - 0x1a4eaffff libdispatch.dylib arm64e 
 <3277bf1eb99436099b30e0186bbf3c25> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
 0x1a4eb0000 - 0x1a4eeafff libdyld.dylib arm64e 
 <ba60cb9e95c53646beedd313e15586cf> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
 0x1a4eeb000 - 0x1a5156fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64e 
 <844c0712322438dcb019d7d4bbbddf17> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
 0x1a5157000 - 0x1a5510fff CoreFoundation arm64e 
 <af3f8e01c1303464ad40c5532d273483>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 0x1a5511000 - 0x1a56bbfff CoreServices arm64e 
 <f036999028923bd39ccb7d9436a145cb>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
 0x1a56bc000 - 0x1a5704fff WirelessDiagnostics arm64e 
 <7bcb1847440837d3ad100dae2432129e>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
 0x1a5705000 - 0x1a577ffff SystemConfiguration arm64e 
 <98796725fd6c39b6af67b09485215996>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
 0x1a5780000 - 0x1a5877fff CoreTelephony arm64e 
 <1865753878113c668fdce282c9999252>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
 0x1a5878000 - 0x1a5d0ffff CFNetwork arm64e 
 <f8c7b81649ab39479309b8975a7ccea0>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork 0x1a5d10000 -
 0x1a641dfff libnetwork.dylib arm64e 
 <267d1486bbbd34efbc93d51b2460b9e9> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
 0x1a641e000 - 0x1a6494fff Accounts arm64e 
 <6c32f1bd45c730a9b5955eac14fb5142>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts 0x1a6495000 -
 0x1a6750fff Foundation arm64e  <5c24ee4a344736bd99106f4d9616d692>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x1a6751000
 - 0x1a6ab0fff ImageIO arm64e  <ce6bb6d9752139118ba03e6b8b147f40> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x1a6aca000 -
 0x1a7062fff CoreGraphics arm64e  <5fbf586867c23779be8102182faff4b0>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
 0x1a7063000 - 0x1a850efff UIKitCore arm64e 
 <05147936b8753ef394db9c8869bb0e34>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
 0x1a850f000 - 0x1a852efff libAccessibility.dylib arm64e 
 <b88743822b4f3f4ea0ca1408c2a86634> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
 0x1a852f000 - 0x1a87b3fff QuartzCore arm64e 
 <dc2644e7e5e43d839110a5ae7e2c8b1f>
 /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x1a87b4000
 - 0x1a881ffff BackBoardServices arm64e  <4827f4d1b8c13c59a7f6d4549556356a>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
 0x1a8820000 - 0x1a88adfff TextInput arm64e 
 <c1bac3dcbbc138beb86782ab8c97227d>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
 0x1a8917000 - 0x1a8cc1fff AppleMediaServices arm64e 
 <3793486f3f3b362b89c78990298a1d23>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleMediaServices.framework/AppleMediaServices
 0x1a8cc2000 - 0x1a8e3dfff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64e 
 <b3a87bce17c73fe1ad8e4f5ac865f27c>
 /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib 0x1a8e3e000 - 0x1a926dfff
 libswiftCore.dylib arm64e  <bd74e14183993d02bd9d2cab2337e1a0>
 /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib 0x1a926e000 - 0x1a9284fff
 UIKitServices arm64e  <4ad58e2b1d973bc38aeaedce472d1cbd>
 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitServices.framework/UIKitServices
 0x1a9285000 - 0x1a93dcfff Preferences arm64e 
 <3cd6d9dd89b03d1aa984f3c2ba0228e2>
```

Comment: can you share the error which you get ?

Comment: Check if you have some difference in debug and release mode, try to run App in release mode.

Comment: @zeytin I don't get any error, app simply starts and after a few seconds black screen it crashes. So I'm not able to retrieve any error

Comment: @guru thanks for the suggestion, but same result

Comment: Looks like you're blocking up main thread (maybe processing large amounts of data etc) on launch; more info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_the_cause_of_common_crashes/addressing_watchdog_terminations

Comment: @shim why would that just happen if not launched by Xcode?

Comment: I don't really have a specific answer for that off the top of my head, but it is not uncommon for your app to behave differently (especially for things like this) when not attached to Xcode.

Comment: thanks @shim ill look into that.

Comment: @shim I appreciate a lot your answer but I just tested the app on a lower end device and the app seems to  be running perfectly like before I installed iOS 14.2 , it must be something else

Comment: That doesn't really prove anything

Comment: Your crash report is fairly clear as to what the underlying cause is. If you don't provide any more details there's not much anyone else can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, "process-launch watchdog transgression: exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds". Your app is taking too long to launch.

The reason this doesn't happen when launching from Xcode is that the watchdog is turned off under those circumstances. But it is still taking too long to launch, even from Xcode!

The reason for taking so long is that you have misunderstood *how* to launch. Do not perform tasks during launch (on the main thread). Your job during launch is to get out of the way and let the device launch the app and get it running. The best thing for you to do during launch is *nothing*. Just stand back.

If you have time-consuming tasks to perform, do them later and on a background thread.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59168773/341994, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296663/341994, etc. As I say in one of those answers, there are excellent WWDC on how to launch. Watch them! Your entire launch philosophy is probably wrong; Apple will set it right, no problem.

Comment: I understand, what I don't understand is why it just happens on the device it has the iOS 14.2 installed, and with the other ones it doesn't just run, it starts inmeditaly. Still I will check on this. thanks @matt